# Highlight row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have a function that will highlight row of the table when a mouse rolls over it. I currently have a function that creates an alternate row color every other row and I would like to modify it rather than creating a separate function. Here's what I have:

```
$(".tblRows tr:even").addClass("altColor");
```

where

```
.altColor TD {
background-color:#f5f5f5
}
```

and my HTML is

```
<table class="tblRows">
...
```

I know there's a jQuery function hover() but I'm not sure how to incorporate it with what I've got. When hovered I'd like it to use class="hilite"

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't just use CSS for this?

```
#myTable tr:hover {
    background: orange;
}
```

Won't work on a `<tr>` in IE6, but will work elsewhere.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/auWGU/

Comment: Uh, I love the simplicity of this method!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.tblRows tr')
    .mouseenter(function() { $(this).addClass('hilite'); })
    .mouseleave(function() { $(this).removeClass('hilite'); };
```

Comment: Thanks @David, didn't notice I forgot it. @santa I suppose you could use `.hover` as the others pointed out. It really depends on what you like best I suppose. :)

Comment: `$(this)` not `this`, it needs to be a jQuery object [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bECGe/) (I deleted the original comment because I wanted to edit in a link to a demo of why the `this` needs to be `$(this)`, which is why the comment I'm being thanked for appears after the comment thanking me...) =)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$(".tblRows tr").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hilite");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hilite");
});
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
$(".tblRows tr").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hilite");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hilite");
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/kQvJ3/

Answer (score 1):

You need the hover-function to add a mouse-over-event-handler to each row in your table.
E.g:

```
$('.tblRows tr').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hilite');
},
function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hilite');
});
```